# Book about a group of adventurers named The Crow

Tags: story-identification

Quite a few years ago I read a fantasy book about a group of adventurers/warriors/mercenaries. This group was named "The Crow". I completely forgot the title of the book and who wrote it and I would like to reread it.

Comment: IRL their was a man who fit that, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Beckwourth

Comment: When was "quite a few years ago"? Five years? Ten years? Twenty? And do you remember whether it was a paperback, hardback, any details about the cover?

Answer (score 6):

It might be [Dawnthief](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawnthief) by James Barclay, published first in 1999. The book (first of the [Chronicles of the Raven](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_The_Raven)) is about:

> The Raven are band of mercenaries, from the continent of Balaia, who are famous, with a reputation for being the best at what they do. As a result, they already have all the money they need and so the fights and missions they choose to do during the books are what they choose to do and not what they are paid to do - this means that they do what they consider to be the just and right thing to do. The Raven have been together ten years before the beginning of DawnThief, and have already lost two members named Kirst and Halyn.
>   Each time a member of the Raven dies they observe their own private rituals, holding a Vigil and promising never to forget the dead member.

The name of the mercenaries' group is *The Raven* instead of *The Crow*, but I immediately thought about this book.

Answer (score 2):

There was also a series of books by Michael Stackpole, a trilogy called The [Dragoncrown War Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DragonCrown_War_Cycle) with a prequel novel, "The Dark Glory War".

The main protagonist in the trilogy is called "Crow", and he leads a small but growing group of adventures on the task of defeating a Queen from the North, Chrytienne, who is determined to restore the Dragon Crown and conquer the land.